# How to Implement caching for a web application

Tags: java, database, caching, web-applications

What are the different ways to cache a web application data, developed using Java and NoSQL database? Databases also provide caching, are they, the only & always the best option to go with, for caching?

How else can I cache my data of users on the application. Application contains very user specific data like in a social network. Are there some simple thumb rules of what type of things should be cached?

Can I also cache my data on the application server using Java ?

Comment: Have you tried memcached? http://memcached.org/

Comment: @user01 - Please share your experience/solution/learnings now...after 5 years. It would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll assume you're building a relatively typical web application that:

1. has a single server used for persistence
2. multiple web servers
3. ties authenticated users to a single server via sticky sessions through a load balancer

Now, with that stated to answer so of your questions. Most persistence, database or NoSQL, likely have some sort of caching built in such that if you execute the same simple query repeatedly (e.g. retrieval by primary key) it's able to cache the result. However, the more complex the query, the less likely persistence can perform caching on it. In addition, if there's only one server for persistence (i.e. no sharding, or write master/read slaves) it quickly becomes the bottleneck. So the application level caching you want to do usually should occur on the web servers to reduce load on the database.

As far as what should be cached, the heuristic is items frequently accessed and/or expensive to generate (in terms of database/web server processing/memory). Typical candidates are the home page and any other landing page of a site - often the best approach for these is generating a static file and serving that. The next pieces depend on your application, but typically the most effective strategy is caching as close to the final result as possible - often the HTML being served. For your social network this might be a list of featured updates or some such.

As far as user sessions are concerned, these are definitely a good candidate for caching. In this case you can probably get a lot of mileage out of judicious use of the web server's session scope (assuming a JSP server). This data lives in memory and is a good place to keep of user specific information shown once a user authenticates on every page (e.g. first and last name).

Now the final thing to consider is dealing with cache invalidation and really is the hard part of all this ([naming stuff is the other hard thing in computer science](http://laughingmeme.org/2005/12/23/there-are-only-two-hard-things-in-computer-science-cache-invalidation-and-naming-things/)). In this case using something like memcached or ehcache as others have mentioned is the right approach. ehcache can easily run in process with your java application and does a good job of expiring things, with policies for least recently used and least frequently used, and allowing you to use both memory and disk for caching. What you'll need to think about is the situations where you need to expire something form the cache ahead of this schedule because data's changed. In this case you need to work through those dependencies in your application's architecture so that it read/writes to the cache as appropriate.

Answer (score 33):

If you want a rule of thumb, here's what Michael Jackson (not *that* Michael Jackson) said:

1. The First Rule of Program Optimization: **Don't do it**.
2. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): **Don't do it yet**.

The ancient tradition is that you don't optimise until you've profiled - that is, until you have hard evidence as to what actually needs to be optimised. Cacheing is a kind of optimisation; it is very likely to be important for your app, but until you are able to put your app under load and look at what objects are taking a long time to obtain (loading from the database or whatever), you won't know what needs cacheing. It really doesn't matter how smart you are, or what advice you get here - until you do that, you **will not know** what needs to be cached.

As for things you can cache, it's anything, but i suppose you can classify it into three groups:

1. Things that have come fresh from the database. These are easy to cache, because at the point at which you go to the database, you have the identifying information you'd need for a cache key (primary key, query parameters, etc). By cacheing them, you save the time taken to get them from the database - this involves IO, so it is likely to be quite large.
2. Things that have been produced by computation in the domain model (news feeds in a social app, perhaps). These may be trickier to cache, because more contextual information goes into producing them; you might have to refactor your code to create a single point where the required information is all to hand, so you can apply cacheing to it. Or you might find that this exists already. Cacheing these will save all the database access needed to obtain the information that goes into making them, as well as all the computation; the time taken for computation may or may not be a significant addition to the time taken for IO. Invalidating cached things of this kind is likely to be much harder than pure database objects.
3. Things that are being sent to the browser - pages, or fragments of pages. These can be quite easy to cache, because in a properly-designed application, they're uniquely identified by either the URL, or the combination of URL and user. Cacheing these will save all the computation in your app; it can even avoid servicing requests, because it can be done by a [reverse proxy](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) sitting in front of your app server. Two problems. Firstly, it uses a huge amount of memory: the page rendered from a few kilobytes of objects could be tens or hundreds of kilobytes in size (my Facebook homepage is 50 kB). That means you have to save a vast amount of computation to make it a better deal than cacheing at the database or domain model layers, and there just isn't that much computation between the domain model and the HTML in a sensibly-designed application. Secondly, invalidation is even harder than in the domain model, and is likely to happen prohibitively often - anything which changes the page or the fragment needs to invalidate the cache.

Finally, the actual mechanism: start with something simple and in-process, like a map with limited size and a least-recently-used eviction policy. That's simple but effective. Something out-of-process like EHCache is more complicated, but has two advantages: you can share caches between multiple processes (helpful if you have a cluster, which you probably will at some point), and you can store data where the garbage collector won't see it, which might save some CPU time (might - this is too big a subject to get into here).

But i reiterate my first point: don't cache until you know what needs to be cached, and once you do, be mindful of the limitations on the benefits of cacheing, and try to keep your cacheing strategy as simple as possible (but no simpler, of course).

Comment: You can start width in-process EHCache right away. There is no development time penalty and you will be better prepared for scaling.